# Groovy Script exist even after deletion in SAP CPI

Tags: sap-cpi

In SAP CPI Message Mapping scenario, I have created a groovy script which produces error. So, I have deleted that script in the mapping and in Reference section. Then I have created a new script with same name but gives error as "Script Name already exists".

Now I need to create a script with the same name.
Anyone suggest how to overcome this issue?